# Firebase Database is not Connecting to PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino

I am working on project where I am pushing real-time gps lat long to firebase from Arduino. But Firebase doesn't allow http request so I am using php website in between to get the data from arduino-sim900a module to php site to firebase code is running fine but firebase database is not updating

```
<?php
require 'firebaseLib.php';
$deviceId = $_GET["deviceid"];
$latitude = $_GET["lat"];
$longitude= $_GET["lon"];
echo($deviceId);
echo($latitude);
echo($longitude);



const DEFAULT_URL = 'my_url';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'my_token';
$DEFAULT_PATH = '/Accounts/Devices/'.$deviceId;

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$_devicestatus= array(
'latitude' => $latitude + 0.0,
'longitude' => $longitude + 0.0,
'battery' => '100'
);


$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL,  DEFAULT_TOKEN);
echo('p');


$firebase->set($DEFAULT_PATH, $_devicestatus); 
echo('7');
$firebase->update($DEFAULT_PATH, $_devicestatus); 
echo('3');
// updates data in Firebase

echo('POST SUCCESSFUL');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets indicates that you are using https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php as the library to access the Firebase Realtime Database.

The fact that you are not receiving an error does not mean that the request was successful, you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/v2.2.0/src/firebaseLib.php#L241-L248) that exceptions are caught and the return value is set to `null` in case of an exception.

You should also know that authenticating requests with a database secret (in your case `DEFAULT_TOKEN`) has been deprecated by Firebase, and to be prepared for the day when Google discontinues support for database secrets, you should migrate to service account based authentication rather sooner than later.

https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php is a library that provides service account based authentication, your code would look something like this:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('/path/to/google-service-account.json');

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$db = $firebase->getDatabase();

$reference = $db->getReference($DEFAULT_PATH);

$reference->set($devicestatus);
print_r($reference->getValue());
```

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of that library :)